# Simple Jquery load function work just in FF but dont work in IE and Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Works fine just in FF:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadContent(id,start) {
   $("#ContentRightBlockTest").load("cast_member.php?_type="+id+"&start="+start+"");   
}  
    </script>
```

whith onload in the body

```
<body onLoad="loadContent('cast',4);">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you don't want to use the body onLoad with jQuery.  jQuery provides a much better browser-independent way to run javascript when the document completely finishes loading.  Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadContent(id,start) {
        $("#ContentRightBlockTest").load("cast_member.php?_type="+id+"&start="+start+"");   
   }
   $(loadContent('cast',4));
    </script>
```

Then remove your body onload.  The $(--something here--); syntax will ensure the enclosed javascript gets run when the document loads.

Alternatively, you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() { loadContent('cast',4); });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Is any code running in Safari?  Do you have any Javascript errors in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the onload event in the body and just slap this in the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ContentRightBlockTest").load("cast_member.php?_type="+id+"&start="+start+"")}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "don't work," so I'm going to go with just a few suggestions instead.

I'm not sure about Safari, but Internet Explorer will cache the results, causing a hiccup in your expectations. You can avoid this by appending a constantly-changing value onto the query-string.

```
function loadContent(id, start) {
  var t = new Date;
  $.get("cast_member.php", {'_type':id,'start':start,'t':t.getTime()}, function(result) {
    $("#ContentRightBlockTest").html(result);
  });
}
```

Additionally, it's advised to wait until the DOM has completely finished loading before firing off any requests. As such, jQuery code is best placed within the `ready()` event of the `document`. Below is a short-hand representation of this containing your function call.

```
$(function(){
  // Fire loadContent() once DOM is loaded
  loadContent('cast', 4);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that your HTML should read like this:

```
<body onload="loadContent('cast',4);">
```

with lower case attributes?